# python; merge dictionaries with each dictionary in a new column of the output csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, append

With the following script, I parse 3 files to one dictionary in python. The dictionaries do not have all similar keys and I want the values of each dictionary in a new column in my output csv file. So the keys must be all in one column, followed by columns each containing the values of the different dictionaries. 
The problem with my script is that is only appending values if they exist, and the result is that the values of the different dictionaries are places in the wrong columns of the output csv file. 
My script is as follows:

```
  def get_file_values(find_files, output_name):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
            if all(x in files for x in find_files):
                outputs = []
                for f in find_files:
                    d = {}
                    with open(os.path.join(root, f), 'r') as f1:
                        for line in f1:
                            ta = line.split()
                            d[ta[1]] = int(ta[0])
                    outputs.append(d)

                d3 = defaultdict(list)
                for k, v in chain(*(d.items() for d in outputs)):
                    d3[k].append(v)

                with open(os.path.join(root, output_name), 'w+', newline='') as fnew:
                    writer = csv.writer(fnew)
                    writer.writerow(["genome", "contig", "genes", "SCM", "plasmidgenes"])
                    for k, v in d3.items():
                        fnew.write(os.path.basename(root) + ',')
                        writer.writerow([k] + v)
                        print(d3)

    get_file_values(['genes.faa.genespercontig.csv', 'hmmer.analyze.txt.results.txt', 'genes.fna.blast_dbplasmid.out'], 'output_contigs_SCMgenes.csv')
```

My output now is:

```
genome contig  genes   SCM     plasmidgenes
Linda     9     359     295    42
Linda     42    1       2      
Linda     73    29      5   
Linda     43    17      6   
Linda     74    4       
Linda     48    11      
Linda     66    27
```

And I want to have it like;

```
genome contig  genes   SCM     plasmidgenes
Linda     9     359     295    42
Linda     42    1       2      0
Linda     73    0       29     5    
Linda     43    17      0      6    
Linda     74    0       0      4        
Linda     48    0       11     0    
Linda     66    27      0      0
```

Comment: Hey. Do you have to use dictionaries for some particular reason? Because using pandas Series and Dataframes would be more suited for this job.

Comment: I have never worked with dataframes, but it is also fine for me to use that. Can you please give me some help with rewriting the script for pandas? The input files are just the opposite as you expect: first the value, than the key (seperated with a space). Therefore, I thought that dictionaries would be a good option.

Comment: Sure I can help. But first of all, I am having a little bit of trouble to visualize your input. Can you post file 1 content just to help me out? I am guessing is something like:

Linda genome \n
9 contig \n
359 genes \n
295 SCM \n
42 plasmidgenes \n

Comment: I have posted what I have and need in a new question, because there I was able to show my files etc. The new question is; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43738909/create-pandas-dataframe-from-multiple-files-in-different-directories

Answer (score 0):

Easiest fix: Check if the value exists, if it does append it, else append a 0 to your data array.

Probably a more complicated fix: Use a different data structure such as Pandas or a two-dimensional array that resembles your data.

Example with two dimensional array:

You would first loop through the files and fill the d3 array with `d3[lineNumber][key]`. e.g. `d3[0]['genome']` would be your first rows first column.

Then you should be able to output the file with the following block:

```
with open(os.path.join(root, output_name), 'w+', newline='') as fnew:
    writer = csv.writer(fnew)

    # write header row
    header = ""
    for k, v in d3[0].items():
        header += k + ','
    writer.writerow(header)

    # write data rows
    for key, row in d3.items():
        line = ""
        line += os.path.basename(root)
        for k, v in row.items():
            line += ',' + v
        writer.writerow(line)
```